# Editing registers (RIP specifically) with ptrace and PTRACE_POKEUSER

Tags: c, process, ptrace

Apparently, something like this is (probably) possible, though `ptrace`'s manual is a little ambiguous. Can someone elaborate on how I'd use `PTRACE_POKEUSER` to modify the user-space of the paused process (and maybe add some sample code), along with how I wouldn't, since the `PTRACE_POKEUSER` section of the docs says something about disallowing some activities? Specifically, I'm looking to modify the `RIP` register, if that means anything.

Thanks.